# Wrong XML string based on XSD c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am new in programming and especially in XML and XSD and I want help.

I have an XSD file which you can find here [InvoicesDoc-v0.5.xsd](https://www.aade.gr/sites/default/files/2019-07/InvoicesDoc-v0.5.xsd)

I convert it with Xsd2Code and with command

> xsd InvoicesDoc-v0.5.xsd /classes

into classes and I try to create an XML string based on that XSD.
My code for creating the XML is

```
 public partial class MyDataOperations
    {
        private Timologio TimologioCurrent { get; set; }
        private StringBuilder ErrorBuilder { get; set; }
        private AadeBookInvoiceType aadeBookInvoiceType { get; set; }
        private InvoicesDoc invoicesDoc { get; set; }

      public MyDataOperations(Timologio timologio)
        {
            TimologioCurrent = timologio;
            invoicesDoc = new InvoicesDoc();
            LengthWarn.WarnBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        }

        public void Create()
        {
            Header();
            Ekdotis();
            Paraliptis();
            Epikefalida();
            Grammes();
            Perilipsi();

        }

        void Header()
        {
            aadeBookInvoiceType= new AadeBookInvoiceType(); 
        }
        void Ekdotis()
        {
            PartyType partyType = new PartyType();
            partyType.vatNumber = TimologioCurrent.Diasafistis.Afm;
            partyType.country = CountryType.GR;
            aadeBookInvoiceType.issuer = partyType;
        }
        void Paraliptis()
        {
            PartyType partyType = new PartyType();
            partyType.vatNumber = TimologioCurrent.Afm;
            partyType.country = CountryType.GR;
            aadeBookInvoiceType.counterpart = partyType;
        }
        void Epikefalida()
        {
            InvoiceHeaderType HeaderType = new InvoiceHeaderType();
            HeaderType.aa = '1';
            HeaderType.issueDate = DateTime.Today;


        }
        void Grammes()
        {
            InvoiceRowType rowType = new InvoiceRowType();
            rowType.lineNumber = '1';
            rowType.invoiceDetailTypeSpecified = true;
            rowType.invoiceDetailType = '1';
            InvoiceRowTypeNetValue value = new InvoiceRowTypeNetValue();
            value.Value = 200;
            rowType.vatCategory = 3;
        }
        void Perilipsi()
        {
            InvoiceSummaryType summaryType = new InvoiceSummaryType();
            summaryType.totalNetValue = 200;
            summaryType.totalVatAmount = 100;
            summaryType.totalWithheldAmount = 0;
            summaryType.totalFeesAmount = 0;
            summaryType.totalStampDutyAmount = 0;
            summaryType.totalOtherTaxesAmount = 0;
            summaryType.totalDeductionsAmount = 0;
            summaryType.totalGrossValue = 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return GetStringMessage();
        }

        public string GetStringMessage()
        {
            return aadeBookInvoiceType.Serialize();
        }
}
```

My problem is that When I create the XML string to send it it has the wrong format.
The XML that I create has the following format

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AadeBookInvoiceType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0">
    <issuer>
        <vatNumber>043529374</vatNumber>
        <country>GR</country>
        <address>Thessaloniki</address>
    </issuer>
    <counterpart>
        <vatNumber>094006956</vatNumber>
        <country>GR</country>
        <address>Thessaloniki</address>
    </counterpart>
    <invoiceHeader>
        <branch>0</branch>
        <aa>1</aa>
        <issueDate>2019-08-05</issueDate>
        <invoiceType>1.1</invoiceType>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
    </invoiceHeader>
    <invoiceSummary>
        <totalNetValue>0</totalNetValue>
        <totalVatAmount>0</totalVatAmount>
        <totalWithheldAmount>0</totalWithheldAmount>
        <totalFeesAmount>0</totalFeesAmount>
        <totalStampDutyAmount>0</totalStampDutyAmount>
        <totalOtherTaxesAmount>0</totalOtherTaxesAmount>
        <totalDeductionsAmount>0</totalDeductionsAmount>
        <totalGrossValue>0</totalGrossValue>
    </invoiceSummary>
</AadeBookInvoiceType>
```

and I want to have an output with the following format

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0">
    <invoice>
        <issuer>
            <vatNumber>#####</vatNumber>
            <country>GR</country>
        </issuer>
        <counterpart>
            <vatNumber>####</vatNumber>
            <country>GR</country>
            <name>string</name>
        </counterpart>
        <invoiceHeader>
            <branch>0</branch>
            <series>1</series>
            <aa>891</aa>
            <issueDate>2017-11-26</issueDate>
            <invoiceType>1.4</invoiceType>
            <vatPaymentSuspension>true</vatPaymentSuspension>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
        </invoiceHeader>
        <invoiceDetails>
            <lineNumber>9870</lineNumber>
            <measurementUnit>1</measurementUnit>
            <invoiceDetailType>1</invoiceDetailType>
            <netValue>5.00</netValue>
            <vatCategory>1</vatCategory>
            <vatExemptionCategory>2</vatExemptionCategory>
            <discountOption>0</discountOption>
            <withheldPercentCategory>10</withheldPercentCategory>
            <feesAmount>0.00</feesAmount>
            <feesPercentCategory>4</feesPercentCategory>
            <otherTaxesPercentCategory>5</otherTaxesPercentCategory>
        </invoiceDetails>
        <invoiceSummary>
            <totalNetValue>5.00</totalNetValue>
            <totalVatAmount>0.00</totalVatAmount>
            <totalWithheldAmount>0.00</totalWithheldAmount>
            <totalFeesAmount>0.00</totalFeesAmount>
            <totalStampDutyAmount>0.00</totalStampDutyAmount>
            <totalOtherTaxesAmount>0.00</totalOtherTaxesAmount>
            <totalDeductionsAmount>0.00</totalDeductionsAmount>
            <totalGrossValue>5.00</totalGrossValue>
        </invoiceSummary>
    </invoice>
</InvoicesDoc>
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong with the convertion from XSD to XML or with my code in c#.
I can't upload the final cs file that is created by the tools because it is too big.

Comment: The XSD created classes with Attributes like [XmlRoot(ElementName="ABC")] above the classes.  The serialization method defaults to the class names.  You can use the Element Name to override the class name which is why you are getting BookInvoiceType instead of InvoicesDoc.  You also need to add another intermediate class for invoice to get your desired results.

Comment: @jdwengCan you give me a little example with code how can I accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize  InvoicesDoc and then change the classes to look like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoicesDoc));

            InvoicesDoc doc = new InvoicesDoc()
            {
                invoice = new AadeBookInvoiceType[] {
                    new AadeBookInvoiceType() 
                    {

                    }
                }
            };

            serializer.Serialize(writer, doc);
        }
    }
    public class InvoicesDoc
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice")]
        public AadeBookInvoiceType[] invoice { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoice")]
    public class AadeBookInvoiceType
    {
        //add the rest of the invoice properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correct I have to edit the cs generated file that created with Xsd2Code with this classes?

Comment: It looks like you are missing the InvoiceDoc that was generated with xsd.exe tool.  And you change the name of the invoice class to AadeBookInvoiceType.

Comment: I upload the generated class file from xsd2code [link]https://filebin.net/bf55oszytsg6q5f4/InvoicesDoc-v0.5.designer.cs?t=ee6s7qs5

Comment: Try downloading from msdn the xsd.exe tool.  Then from cmd.exe >.\xsd.exe /c /l:cs invoice.xsd (or what ever name you are using for the schema).  I do not know hwat the xsd2code actually does.  I prefer to use the microsoft tool.

Comment: I already tried to create the classes with the xsd as I mention , the problem with that is that xsd doesnt create serialize method and it doesn't create the XML at all. I use serialize to create te XML and read it from memory just to sent it.

Comment: I updated my code to include sample serialize code.  You xsd2code is very similar to the output of the xsd.exe and has the class InvoicesDoc.  Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Debugging XML Serialization is straight forward. 1) You make sure the Xml file is getting updated by checking the Date of the file 2) You make sure the classes you are serializing are the same ones you put data into 3) When data is missing you make sure the properties are public.  Properties that are not public are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your code. This seems to export a correct XML format but this means that I have to rewrite all AadeBookInvoiceType properties by hand.

Comment: I think I found the problem but I am not sure how to fix it. The problem is in the public string GetStringMessage()
        {
            return aadeBookInvoiceType.Serialize();
        }
If I change it to retun invoicesDoc.Serialize it return the root of invoicesDoc but doesnt fill the aadeBookInvoiceType data

Comment: There isn't enough code posted for me to help.  The Serilaize() code isn't shown and the ToString() is not used.   You are also missing a statement like this : invoicesDoc.invoice = new AadeBookInvoiceType[] {aadeBookInvoiceType};

Comment: If I add the invoicesDoc.invoice = new AadeBookInvoiceType[] {aadeBookInvoiceType}; it gives me an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Ektelonistis.Helper.Classes.AadeBookInvoiceType[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Ektelonistis.Helper.Classes.AadeBookInvoiceType>'

Comment: In my posted code above I used : public AadeBookInvoiceType[] invoice { get; set; }.  It looks like in your code you have public Enumerable<AadeBookInvoiceType> invoice (or something similar).  So I think this will work : invoicesDoc.invoice = new List<AadeBookInvoiceType>() {aadeBookInvoiceType};

Comment: You are great. It worked at last. Thanks a lot. I don't know how to thank you.